# Wordpress how to remove auto generated &nbsp; in the navigation menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-menu-item

I uploaded the pages including my `header.php` to wordpress and my header have auto generated `&nbsp` in it together with #text.

I tried adding this code but nothing happens.

```php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Are there any solutions for this?

Edit:
This is where "&nbsp" shows up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvQgI.jpg

Comment: In addition to removing the filter, there are other ways too, but you need to be more specific. There could be many sections and subsections in `header.php` file. Where do you see the "auto nbsp"? Is it a custom theme or you've created it? Please be more specific and give us more details so that we could try to debug it for you. Please take a moment and read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ruvee This is where I saw the nbsp and this is a custom theme that I code from scratch. https://imgur.com/a/PT9GWDi

Comment: @Ruvee thank you so much! I am stuck with this for more than an hour and I have been applying some PHP functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your theme is outputting `&nbsp` in the "nav menu items". So try to use the following code, see if it removes those extra spaces!

```php
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'rempving_extra_spaces_from_nav_menu_items', 999);

function rempving_extra_spaces_from_nav_menu_items($items)
{
  $items = str_replace(' &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;',  '', $items);
  return $items;
}
```

Code goes into your `functions.php` file of your theme.

Comment: Ok that's fine, we'll make it work! So try to increase the priority of the filter hook from `10` to, let's say, `999`. See if it works.

Comment: Still not working, This is what my team mate says regarding this problem "I changed something inside a predetermined tag from the Wordpress admin panel, but it collapsed." (collapsed means nbsp are added in nav links)

Comment: Just updated my answer, please give it a shot!

Comment: While testing, is it now working. I'll accept this as the answer! Thank you so much :)